# Should my API method return a 401 or a 204?

Tags: api-design

I have a client coded in JavaScript. This client calls an API method on my server which is coded in PHP. This API method is "GET /user" and could return a 200 status or a 204 status.

The 200 status is intended for authenticated users.
The 204 status is intended for guest users and can in the future become a 200 with information about these guest users (like frontend autorizations).

I had a confrontation with developers who think my API should return a 401 status in case the user is a guest. But I said there was no client error since the client just ask for the authentication state + some information about the non guest user.

So my question is pretty simple: is there a missconception in my API ?

Comment: Do not change the meaning of status codes (https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/). If you want to further fine-tune response, add extra header entries or return meaningful body for non-success cases. A user is either authorized to connect to an api method or not - thus he will either get a response from the business logic or a 401. It should not make any difference if he is authorized as guest or as regular user.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest neither.

Take a look at [section 10 of the HTTP/1.1 RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and see if you can match your response code with what is being returned.

If you are returning data from GET /users (regardless of authenticated client or guest) then `204 No Content` is not appropriate:

> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

A `401 Unauthorized` is only appropriate if the method being called is only accessible to authenticated clients. You are essentially telling the client that they have done something they are not allowed to.

If both an authenticated user and a guest user are expected clients of your API I would suggest returning a `200 OK` to both clients and have any differentiation made clear in the returned body itself.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with the answer of @Johnson. Do not change the meaning of the status codes. If it is a valid request, you should respond with 200.

The problem here is that the endpoint you define is not a resource-oriented endpoint (problem = REST API design guidelines are not really applicable as they are mostly focused on resource oriented APIs). `/user` in your case seems to return a state rather than a resource. `401` is good for telling the client that it is not authenticated and thus cannot fetch the requested resource.

In your case it is just an informative endpoint for the client to check its login state and both states (logged in and not logged in) are successful answers from a technical point of view and thus require a `200` response. To tell the client the login state you should use the response body, not the status code.